# JSON using parse or stringify correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

This is what I'm getting from server

```
['model':{"category":[{"id":1}],"food":[{"id":1}].... // long json here
```

How can I use jquery/javascript to parse to get category id and food id? I tried to use

```
JSON.parse(data)
```

or

```
JSON.stringify(data)
```

And after that, doing

```
$.each(data, function (i, x) {
```

it will give me each letter of all array. How can I parse it correctly, getting the ids that I want?

Comment: How are you getting it from the server?

Comment: What you need to iterate over ? Do you need to iterate over category ?

Comment: The single-quotes around "model" are invalid JSON syntax. If your server is really sending that, you'll get errors  when you try to parse it.

Comment: did you try accessing data directly? you are probably using a method like $.getJSON that parses the response for you. Also [model:{}] is wrong it should be [{"model": {..}}] instead

Comment: @Pointy YES! It's invalid, you are right, I saw it on console. Thanks for pointing that!

Answer (score 0):

`JSON.parse(data)` will turn the data you showing into a JavaScript object, and there are a TON of ways to use the data from there. Example:

```
var parsedData = JSON.parse(data),
    obj = {};

for(var key in parsedData['model']){
    obj[key] = parsedData['model'][key]['id'];
}
```

Which would give you a resulting object of this:

```
{category:1, food:1}
```

This is based on the limited example of JSON you provided, the way you access it is entirely dependent on its structure. Hopefully this helps get you started, though.

Answer (score -1):

You want to use JSON.parse(), but it returns the parsed object, so use it thusly:

```
var parsed = JSON.parse(data);
```

then work with parsed.